# Add fractions to auto-correct in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I see in Google Docs you can go to "Tools - Preferences" and then add new equations to the auto correct function.

Example if you type "1/2" it converts it to a smaller looking neater looking ½.

Is there a way to add new fractions that are not already in auto correct?

Answer (score 3):

Of course. At the top of that list under `Tools > Preferences` are two blank spaces for you to add the "Replace" and "With" values.

[image: screen shot of preferences menu]

Of course, you'll need to be able to paste a single character for the "neater looking" fraction. You can use the character map that comes with most OSes, or there are a few sites out there that can display lots of different characters for you. (Unfortunately, it seems that in most cases there are only fractions available for halves, thirds, quarters, fifths, sixths, and eighths, which Google already has in the list.)

Comment: To find some character, do a web search, eg for `5/8 character` or `five eighths character` or say, `unicode flower`.